# Unexpected Variable Not Defined error

Tags: dom, vb6

I'm trying to resurrect an older VB6 app and when compiling it throws an error:

Code:

```
Set mDom = DHTMLMessage.DOM
```

Error message:

> Variable Not Defined

(on  DHTMLMessage).

I have searched google and various VB6 sites but cannot understand the issue. Also read a bit about DOM but frankly I am not a solid VB6 guy. As far as I can tell References are correct - I think.

I have checked for missing code but still cannot work out why this error is appearing.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `DHTMLMessage` is probably a DHTMLEdit control.  Maybe it got removed from the Form somehow?

Comment: Confirmed - That was it @Bob77, appreciated.